# Android changing the width of the navigation drawer panel programmatically

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I've used the Navigation Drawer template presents in Android Studio.
In the layout of my activity I have this following code:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.smedilepaolo.newsfeed.NavigationDrawer.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

What I need is to change programmatically the width of the panel.
I think that the right zone to change it is this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_feed);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

....
```

But I can't understand how can achieve my target.

/*** UPDATE ***/

The icon of the drawer panel is not showed in the action bar

```
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

            mDrawerListView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Resources resources = getResources();
                    float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 240, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
                    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerListView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.width = (int) (width);
                    mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
            });

            selectItem(position);
        }
    });



    mDrawerListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Resources resources = getResources();
            float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels-1, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
            DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = (int) (width);
            mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
    });
```

That's the selectItem method

```
    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

....
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the code generated from the Navigation Drawer template, you can change the width of the panel by adding this code to the onCreateView() method in the NavigationDrawerFragment.

```
 mDrawerListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Resources resources = getResources();
            float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
            DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = (int) (width);
            mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

To disable pan gestures on DrawerLayout:

//NavigationDrawerFragment

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
}
```

To open/close DrawerLayout:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerListView);
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerListView);
```

To prevent the icon of the drawer panel disappears, change setOnItemClickListener method as follow:

```
mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
});
```

And modify the overridden onDrawerClose method as follow:

```
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
    if (!isAdded()) {
        return;
    }

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

    Resources resources = getResources();
    float width = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 240, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerListView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) (width);
    mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);

    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works! I use your code to automatically set the width to the max possibile. After the first click on an item I re-use your code to resize the width to 240dp. But unfortunately it remove the icon of the drawer menu in the leff top corner of the sidebar... I don't know why... How can I fix? Is it also possible to automatic open the drawer menu and Disable pan gestures (and reable that after the first click on a item)

Comment: I fix the icon problem using resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels-1 instead of  resources.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels!
so my remaining questions are now 2. Is it possibile to open the drawer panel programmatically and disable pan gestures?
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer... I've update my question... Now remains only one bug... It's more then one hour that I'm triyng to solve it. After the resize of the panel.. the icon of the drawer panel bar is not showed in the action bar... but if you make a swipe it will appears.. How can I force the icon to be showed?

Comment: Try editing your code as I suggest to you on the edited answer, please :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfect... but I can't understand why this work... can you explain me? thanks

Comment: I don’t know for sure, because I didn't check the sources. But I think it has to do with the time that the Drawer performs some calculations. At the time onDrawerClosed is called, we’re good to resize it without affect its natural state.

Comment: I'm glad that i could help you :)