# resize Drawer width based on text content in android

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a navigation Drawer, the left side is the left navigation drawer, containing TextView "***detailsTxt***". This contains dynamic text, and I want the navigation drawer to be resized to fit the TextView when the user opens the drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout mlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/app_bg">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/topNavigator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_white_space">
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="Ayman Salah"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

<!-- drawer layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:id="@+id/leftBar"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="start|left">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/nbackground">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailsTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="string/sample_details"
                android:textColor="@android:color/widget_edittext_dark" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add listeners for Drawer

> Open/Close events

and

Add this code in `onDrawerOpen()`, found from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25588447/1994950) :

```
LinearLayout mDrawerListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftBar);
 mDrawerListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerListView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = (int) 100;  // for example
            mDrawerListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

and set `layout_width="0dp"` in xml file

Comment: I am not asking how to change the Drawer width, I know how to do this. I am asking how to change the Drawer width to fit the Text,

Comment: You need to increase width when text is long right ?

Comment: Yes exactlly, I want to resize the width of drawer

Comment: You need to provide width `params.width = (int) 100;  // for example` here according to your textView `textView.getText().toString().length`

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the *Navigation Draw* with a zero width, i.e. `android:layout_width="0dp"`, and then execute the snippet below in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.

```
// Programatically assigns a custom width to a DrawerLayout.
this.getDrawerLayout().addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
    /** Fire-and-forget programmatic width implementation for the DrawerLayout. */
    @Override public final void onDrawerSlide(final View pDrawerView, final float pSlideOffset) {
        // Recalculate the new LayoutParams.
        pDrawerView.setLayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams((DrawerLayout.LayoutParams)pDrawerView.getLayoutParams()));
        // Stop listening for future events, once we've configured the size once. (We know the DrawerLayout is the direct parent of the DrawerView.)
        ((DrawerLayout)pDrawerView.getParent()).removeDrawerListener(this);
    }
    /** A method used to define the new LayoutParams of the DrawerView. */
    private final DrawerLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams(final DrawerLayout.LayoutParams pLayoutParams) {
        /** TODO: Compute your width here! (i.e pLayoutParams.width = X) **/
        // Return the LayoutParams.
        return pLayoutParams;
    }
});
```