# How can I set the width of a slide-in menu (NavigationView/DrawerLayout)?

Tags: android

I have a NavigationView set up so that every time my hamburger icon is pressed a menu slides in from the left. The problem I'm facing is that the menu covers the entire width of the screen, rather than any value I give it in the XML. Everything is darkened when it's open. It is a transparent black background (I guess by default).

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:entries="@array/menuitems"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I make my NavigationView only take up a certain width of the screen rather then the entirety of it? Appreciate any advice.

EDIT:

Screenshot of the drawer when it's open (as you can see the whole width of the screen is darkened by the drawer's background)

[image]

Comment: What do you actually want for your navigation drawer? `DrawerLayout` only supports two children (the main content and the drawer content) yet you have three children in your XML. Can you include a screenshot of what you currently have?

Comment: Maybe this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587656/android-changing-the-width-of-the-navigation-drawer-panel-programmatically) can help.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I posted a screenshot like you requested. John I was lookin at that post not too long ago, it didn't seem to do anything for me (could not tag more than one person for some reason)..

Answer (score 0):

First things first, Your drawer layout should have two child views. one that hosts the main content, one that will be the nav drawer. In this case your list view is coming up as the navigation drawer.

Also, you are mistaken about the navigation drawer(in this case the ListView) taking up the entire space. its taking only 240 dp. The rest of the main view will be in shadow(default behavior). You can see that its taking only 240 dp if you see where the separator lines between list view items end. The transparent background seems to have confused you.

Comment: Ah OK I removed the ListView now I can see a background on the drawer and the transparency looks fine. Thanks